# How to save best validation score results i.e. save split number 5 out of 6 splits

Tags: python, machine-learning, train-test-split

I have split my data into a time series split of 6 splits and the best score for my design is in the 5th split. I'd like to get help with how I can save the plot for the best split, in other words I can save the result for split 5. I am trying compare the accuracy of a SVR prediction and a RNN prediction.

Below is a snippet of my SVR design (maybe this could allow for anyone to point me to the right direction)

```
timeseries_split = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=6) 


for train_index, test_index in timeseries_split.split(X)

  X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
  y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
  SVR=svm.SVR(kernel='rbf',C=1,gamma=80).fit(x_train,y_train) 
  rbf = SVR.predict(x_test)
  plt.plot( rbf)
  plt.show()
```

Help with saving the 5th score in a variable if possible or any other method will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the `score` in each iteration and save the best score and best split data:

```
timeseries_split = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=6) 

bestScore = -1.0
bestRbf = None
for train_index, test_index in timeseries_split.split(X)
  X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
  y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
  SVR=svm.SVR(kernel='rbf',C=1,gamma=80).fit(x_train,y_train) 
  newScore = SVR.score(x_test)
  if newScore > bestSoFar:
     bestSoFar = newScore
     bestRbf = SVR.predict(x_test)
plt.plot(bestRbf)
plt.show()
```

Note that the above is a bit better than your requested solution: *this* one will find the best split - so it does not require hard-coding of the fifth one like in your question.